# How can I remove the child node name from the metrics sent to Cloudwatch?

Tags: java, kotlin, amazon-cloudwatch, metrics, ktor

I am working with a Java API built with Ktor. It posts metrics to CloudWatch using the MicrometerMetrics feature. My issue is that I have created an interceptor which is cluttering the route name in CloudWatch.

Here follows the interceptor:

```
fun Route.test(callback: Route.() -> Unit): Route {
    val routeTest = createChild(object : RouteSelector(1.0) {
        override fun evaluate(context: RoutingResolveContext, segmentIndex: Int): RouteSelectorEvaluation =
            RouteSelectorEvaluation.Constant
    })
    routeTest.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
        call.response.header("X-Next-Polling-In", pollTime)
    }
    callback(routeTest)
    return routeTest
}
```

And here is how the route for the request `/users`, intercepted by the previous interceptor, is shown in CloudWatch:

```
/users/my.package.TestInterceptor$test$routeTest$1@6cdas3a85
```

Is there any way to remove the child node name or hardcode an unique value instead of **my.package.TestInterceptor$test$routeTest$1@6cdas3a85**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue by overridding the `toString` method on the `RouteSelector` as follows:

```
fun Route.test(callback: Route.() -> Unit): Route {
    val routeTest = createChild(object : RouteSelector(1.0) {
        override fun evaluate(context: RoutingResolveContext, segmentIndex: Int): RouteSelectorEvaluation =
            RouteSelectorEvaluation.Constant

        override fun toString() = "customName"

    })
    routeTest.intercept(ApplicationCallPipeline.Call) {
        call.response.header("X-Next-Polling-In", pollTime)
    }
    callback(routeTest)
    return routeTest
}
```

This leads to the following route name:

```
/users/customName
```